# TikZ : Ring graph with symbol in nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying write symbols in nodes in a ring graph with TikZ.
Nervetheless, my example doesn't work :

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5,vertex/.style={draw,circle}]

\foreach \letter [count=\c from 0] in {1,2,$\tau$,D,E,F,G,H} {

\node[vertex] (\letter) at ({-360/10*\c+157.5}:4cm) {\letter};

}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Does anyone has a solution to fix the issue due to the term $\tau$ ?
Is there a way to delcare this symbol in a way that it appears in a node ?

Comment: Welcome! What does 'doesn't work' mean?

Comment: I don't think you can use `$\tau$` as a node name. Try calling them e.g. `n\c` or whatever instead of `\letter`. (Just a guess - I don't know what the issue is, after all.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this works:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
vertex/.style={draw,circle}]

\foreach \i [count=\j from 0] in {1,2,$\tau$,D,E,F,G,H}
{
\node[vertex] (n\j) at (157.5 - \j*360/10:4cm) {\i};
}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

as can be seen, code is slightly rearranged and names of variables are changed.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Indeed, i will pay more  attention to the use of "n\" !

Comment: I have one more question : how do you proceed to draw vertices between these nodes, when some node names are symbol ?

Comment: no one have symbol for name. vertices names are n1, n2, ... n8. this is main differences between your and mine code.

Comment: I see ! That's answer to my last question thank you !